# Javascript HTML button click not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I've created a login system using HTML, JavaScript, Ajax and PHP.

I'm trying to implement the log out function now, here's what I have:

First there is a div in my html, which says welcome to anyone on the site not logged in:

```
<div id="welcome" style="postion:absolute; top:0; float:right;">Welcome to SIK!!!!</div>
```

I then have a JavaScript function which is called when a user is logged in or registered to amend the div to say hi to the specific user, and show a log out button.

```
function show_logged_in(success)
{

    var is_logged_in = success;

    var dataString = {"reg":invalid, "login":invalid,"is_logged_in":is_logged_in};

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"PHP/class.ajax.php",
        data:dataString,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(username) {
            alert("User is shown");
            user = username;
            $('#welcome').html('<p>Hi ' + user + '</p><p><button id="logout_but" 
   type="button">Log Out</button></p>');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("ERROR in show_logged_in");
        }
    });
}
```

And then when the user clicks logout, in my main js file there is a function:

```
$("#logout_but").click(ui.logout);
```

here is my main js file altogether:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


//----------Login/Register Gui --------------
$('#load-new').hide();
$('#reg').hide();
$('#login').hide();

//create new instance of gui class
var ui = new Gui();

//if login_but is clicked do ui.login function
$('#login_but').click(ui.login);
//if reg_but is clicked do ui.register function
$('#reg_but').click(ui.register);
//if login_sumbit button is clicked do ui.login_ajax function
$("#login_submit").click(ui.login_ajax);

$("#reg_submit").click(ui.register_ajax);

$("#logout_but").click(ui.logout);

});
```

So now you can see the order of the calls, and also the click function that is called for the logout button is:

```
this.logout = function() {

    alert("clicked");

    var dataString = {"is_logged_out":invalid};

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"PHP/class.logout.php",
        data:dataString,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(success){
            alert("User is logged out");
            $('#welcome').html('<p>Welcome to SIK</p>');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('ERROR in log out');
        }
    })

}
```

As you can see I have and alert at the top of the last function I posted to show me if the function is actually being called.

My problem is when I click the logout button nothing happens. I also don't see the alert, thus the problem is occurring on the click.

Any help with this situation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you create the logout button dynamically and AFTER the click handler is trying to attach itself to the element in your main js file. As a result, the handler doesn't find the `#logout_but` element and therefore doesn't attach to anything.

To fix that, you could use a delegate instead of a click handler:

Replace this:

```
$("#logout_but").click(ui.logout);
```

with

```
$("#welcome").on("click", "#logout_but", ui.logout);
```

Comment: I thought this may be the problem but i wasnt sure what was being called when it should be hence why i asked you guys! so thanks. Where about are you suggesting i put this line of code and replacing what? thanks again

Comment: Ok i sussed where you meant now! thanks it works!, is there anyway to refresh the page to send the user back to the login/register div/page with javascript/jquery ??